# Issues with HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, httpresponse, httpcontext

I have written a class which gets the post data using jquerypost and then perform some crud operations. Its works fine adding stuff to the database , but it doesnt redirects to the page when passing certain data , below is the code :

```
 $('#clickme').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            indx = $("#DropDownList1 option:selected").index();
            indx += 1;
            var test = $("#DropDownList" + (indx + 1));
            var url = "/Base/performOperations/shootme/"
            jQuery.post(url, { name: jQuery("#name").val(), email: jQuery("#email").val(), federation: jQuery(test).val(), selectedscheme: jQuery("#DropDownList1").val() },
       function (data) {

           if (data == scheme1) {
               window.location = "http://www.openme.com"
           }

       });

        });



namespace pw
{
  public class performOperations
{
    public static string ShootMe() {

        HttpRequest post = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string name = post["name"];
        string email = post["email"];
        string selectedscheme = post["selectedscheme"];
        string federation = post["federation"];

        string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mydb"];
       string sql = "INSERT INTO  dbo.mydb(Email,Name,schemes,LoginDate,schemeType) VALUES(@email,@name,@scheme,@dateTime,@federation)";
            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn, CommandType.Text, sql,
                new SqlParameter("@email", email),
                new SqlParameter("@name", name),
                new SqlParameter("@scheme", selectedscheme),
                new SqlParameter("@dateTime", DateTime.Now),
                new SqlParameter("@federation", federation));




        return selectedscheme;
    }
    }

    }
```

Any ideas why the redirect doesnt takes place, or am i doing it in a wrong way , i need to redirect to a particular page once the data is injected to the db.
Any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling the `POST` method using `AJAX`, redirection at server side will not work.

You will have to redirect it at client side after request completion using `javascript` the request.

```
$('#clickme').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            indx = $("#DropDownList1 option:selected").index();
            indx += 1;
            var test = $("#DropDownList" + (indx + 1));
            var url = "/Base/sample/Hello/"
            jQuery.post(url, { name: jQuery("#name").val(), email: jQuery("#email").val(), federation: jQuery(test).val(), selectedscheme: jQuery("#DropDownList1").val() },
       function (data) {

           if (data == "shoothim") {
               window.location = "http://www.cuthishead.com"
           }
           else if(data == "shoother")
           {
                window.location = "http://www.chopherbody.com"
           }
           else if(data == "shootboth")
           {
                window.location = "http://www.fulldeath.tv"
           }
       });
```

Comment: i have added the jquery in my question , so u mean i should return d data to jquery and then perform if else statement.

Comment: how can i check the function data , i mean how can i debug the jquery , i need to know if the scheme is being passed to the function, coz currently nothing is happening

Comment: You have to return selectedscheme from the server side and have to match the value in your javascript function function (data){}

Comment: still it doesnt redirects , i have debugged the class , its defo returning the scheme type , but i guess there is an issue with the function(data)

Comment: put `alert(data);` and check what you get

Answer (score 1):

- return `selectedscheme` or URL from your page method
- set `window.location` based on web method result on jquery
- need to set `WebMethod` attribute for your C# method

Check [Using jQuery to Call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods – By Example](http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/11/07/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-by-example.aspx)

Comment: how can i check the function data , i mean how can i debug the jquery , i need to know if the scheme is being passed to the function, coz currently nothing is happening

Comment: dunno why its returning [objectdocument] instead of schemetype

Comment: May be jQuery can't identify content type text or json etc. you need to give that.

Comment: how to do that ? as i am not using json